# undefined reference to `llvm::EnableABIBreakingChecks'

Tags: llvm

I was trying out to run the kaleidoscope example:

https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl02.html#full-code-listing

And the compilation errors follows:

```
clang++ -v -g -O3 toy.cpp  `llvm-config --cxxflags`

clang version 8.0.0 (trunk 350458) (llvm/trunk 350456)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/local/bin/clang-8" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -disable-free -main-file-name toy.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=limited -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir /usr/local/lib/clang/8.0.0 -I /usr/local/include -D _GNU_SOURCE -D _DEBUG -D __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5.4.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5.4.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/lib/clang/8.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -O3 -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /root -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 211 -fno-rtti -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o /tmp/toy-e7c869.o -x c++ toy.cpp -faddrsig
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 based upon LLVM 8.0.0svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5.4.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5.4.0
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.

 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../.. -L/usr/local/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/toy-e7c869.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/toy-e7c869.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `llvm::EnableABIBreakingChecks'
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Essentially how to overcome the error "/tmp/toy-e7c869.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `llvm::EnableABIBreakingChecks'"?

Comment: Question seemed to duplicate

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805007/compilation-failing-on-enableabibreakingchecks

Answer (score 9):

For the toy example:

https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl02.html#full-code-listing

And my clang++ version:

```
root@877aa7b58ab3:~# llvm-config --version
8.0.0svn
root@877aa7b58ab3:~# clang++ --version
clang version 8.0.0 (trunk 350458) (llvm/trunk 350456)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
```

The solution is to compile it the following way:

```
# Compile
clang++ -O3 -c $(llvm-config --cxxflags) toy.cpp -o toy.o
clang++ toy.o $(llvm-config --ldflags --libs) -lpthread -lncurses
```

And thereafter execute run:

./a.out

Reference:

https://github.com/halide/Halide/issues/1112

[Compilation failing on EnableABIBreakingChecks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805007/compilation-failing-on-enableabibreakingchecks)

Comment: You can do it with 1 line: `clang++-9 -g -O3 fun.cpp \`llvm-config-9 --cxxflags --ldflags --libs\` -o fun`

Comment: /bin/bash: llvm-config: command not found

Comment: llvm-config-6.0 --cxxflags